# Rational point oracle for smooth projective varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory, computability-theory

You have an oracle that decides if a smooth projective variety over $\mathbb{Q}$ has a $\mathbb{Q}$-point.

Can you then algorithmically decide if an arbitrary variety over $\mathbb{Q}$ has a $\mathbb{Q}$-point?

I guess by resolution of singularities we always have a proper birational map $X\to Y$ with $X$ smooth. Then Abhyankar's result on ruled fibers would probably be enough to conclude but I am not sure about the details.

Comment: Just a comment: you might find this article of Poonen relevant (http://www-math.mit.edu/~poonen/papers/chatelet.pdf)

Comment: I agree with RP_'s deleted answer that there does not appear to be an obvious way. However, since your premise is probably far out of reach from what we can do today, a *proof* that such a conditional algorithm does *not* exist seems equally unlikely. Of course you probably mean something more specific (but less well-defined), such as an 'immediate reduction' to the smooth projective case, as opposed to someone just solving this without your assumption (and winning the Fields medal).